# The "average" in average rate of change comes from sum of instantaneous rate of change divided by number of rates of change?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

To show what I mean here is a graph of $y = x^2$.

[image]

The red line represents AROC from $a$ to $b$.

The blue lines represent the IROC at some points $x$, where $a<x<b$

If I were to calculate the gradients of those blue lines, add them up and divide by the number of lines I used, would I get the average rate of change? If this is true; is this why the "average" exists in average rate of change?

Comment: You cannot simply "add up" the gradients of the tangents as there are an infinite number of them over the interval.   But you can do something similar with integration, and find the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).  You might then think both that the average rate of change is the average of the instantaneous rates of change over an interval, and that the instantaneous rate of change at a point is the limit of the average rates of change around that point as the interval tends to $0$

Comment: Take care about what interval you are averaging or integrating over: with speed (the change in distance per unit of time) the interval must be a time interval, not a distance interval.  If you travel at 60km/h for 60km (1 hour) and then at 30km/h for another 60km (2 hours), then the average speed is not $45 = \frac{60\times 60+30\times 60}{60+60}$ but is instead $40 = \frac{60\times 1+30\times 2}{1+2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is a qualified "yes".

I say "qualified" because you have to be careful that you add up the lines in a way that fairly reflects the way you drew them.
Also, to be sure of getting an answer that exactly agrees with the "average",
rather than only approximately agreeing, you may have to take a limit where you reduce the space between $x$ points toward zero.

For an example of being careful about how you add up the lines, if you took $a=-1$ and $b=1,$ the average rate of change is zero.
If you take gradients of blue lines at points chosen symmetrically around the $y$ axis you will get the same result,
but if you take, say, gradients at $x=-1$ and $x=-\frac12$ and then take gradients at a hundred positive values of $x$ at intervals of $0.01$ between $x$ values,
you will get a lopsided result.

You can guard against such a lopsided result in either of two ways: you can insist that the gradients be taken at points uniformly spaced between $a$ and $b,$
or you can take a weighted average where the weight of each gradient depends on how far away the nearby gradients were taken.

Regarding the possible need to take a limit,
your observation is essentially the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.
That is, if you are looking at a graph of $y=F(x)$ where $F$ is a differentiable function,
then the gradient at each point of the graph is $F'(x).$
Define the function $f$ by $f(x) = F'(x).$
Then
$$ F(b) - F(a) = \int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx. $$

Now suppose you evaluate the integral using a Riemann sum with uniform intervals.
The sum with $n$ intervals is the sum of $n$ terms
of the form $f(x_i) \Delta x,$ where $\Delta x = (b - a)/n$:

$$ f(x_1)\frac{b-a}n + f(x_2)\frac{b-a}n + \cdots + f(x_n)\frac{b-a}n 
 = \frac{f(x_1) + f(x_2) + \cdots + f(x_n)}{n} (b - a). $$

That is, the integral is just $b - a$ times the average of the instantaneous $f(x_i)$ values,
whereas $F(b) - F(a)$ is just $b - a$ times the average rate of change.

But as you may be aware, you don't always get the exact value of an integral on the first try when doing a particular Riemann sum with some finite number of terms.
You may need to look at what happens in the limit as $n \to \infty$
in order to get an accurate value of the integral.

Comment: Wow, I never knew I was progressing towards something much bigger. Your explanation was concise(+1) and helped me grasp the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, by connecting areas under curves to the net change of its antiderivative at given points. Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 2):

Average rate of change of a function $f$ over an interval $[a,b]$ is defined to be $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$ This gives the slope of the line joining $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$. It signifies what steady (constant) rate of change of the function would be required to get from $(a,f(a))$ to $(b,f(b))$

For instance if $f(3)=11$ and $f(5)=23$, then over the length $2$ interval from $x=3$ to $x=5$, the function changed by $23-11=12$ units. This amounts to an average of $\frac{12}{2}=6$ units of change in $f$ per unit of change in $x$ over the given $x$-interval.